# Express an even number as a sum of primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that every even natural number grater than $2$ can be expressed as a sum of two prime numbers.
No idea how to prove this. Can you help? thanks

Comment: You might want to have a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture

Comment: Let me know if you find a proof of this. We can publish it together :-).

Comment: You are not alone.

Comment: Tough course you are taking, if this is homework! Solving it would put you on the front pages of newspapers.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Some of the conjectures in the past were solved by **mistake** in the past.(Teachers left them as open problems in home assignments).

Comment: I believe there is only one documented case. Memory fails about the name.

Comment: There's one such thread [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54513/the-story-about-milnor-proving-the-fary-milnor-theorem) on mathoverflow.

Comment: Is it April $1^{\text{st}}$ again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is known as [Goldbach's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture). This still remains unproved till date. I bet you will make a great fame if you find the proof. All the best with that.:)

Comment: got it, my lecturer trolled me, didn't know of this conjecture, thanks for link